# Should a journal ever reveal the name of an anonymous reviewer?

Tags: peer-review

Recently, the [single-blind peer-review process](http://blogs.plos.org/everyone/2015/05/01/plos-one-update-peer-review-investigation/#.VUO6vdTtlT0.twitter) failed to appropriately deal with highly sexist comments. An anonymous reviewer provided a sexist review and the Academic Editor forwarded it on. They have since blacklisted the reviewer and asked the Academic Editor to step down. While I think that blind peer review provides useful protection for reviewers, are Academic Editors generally provided anonymity? Further, is there any precedence for when a journal should reveal the name of a reviewer?

Comment: Do you really want to ask about the academic *editor* in the penultimate sentence? This makes the question somewhat overly broad.

Comment: Well, for instance if it was found that the reviewer plagiarized and/or stole from the work he reviewed, I think protecting his anonymity would be entirely inappropriate.

Comment: The review process of PLOS One did not fail. One reviewer made sexist comments, and the editor failed to take appropriate action. How can you blame that on PLOS One's _process_?

Comment: FWIW I'd lay some of the 'blame' here on the widely-used process of anonymous peer-review. Would the reviewer dare write what s/he did if s/he knew their comments were definitely going to be published for all the world to see?

Comment: @rmounce: At the end of the day, it all comes down to definitions, but for some interpretation of these words, the review process did indeed utterly fail – in the sense of not producing the desired outcome at all. However, there is no economically reasonable way to design the process in a way that such failures are completely avoided or at least neglibly unlikely. Therefore the process is arguably not the one to blame.

Comment: @rmounce and then the authors filed a complaint and the publisher ignored it until they were publicly called out. That seems like an utter failure to me.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft potentially it is too broad if we include editors, but I have never heard of anonymous editors before this.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think I agree, but I am not sure if I have ever read about it happening.

Comment: @StrongBad many journals, including PNAS and the whole PLOS family, keep the handling editor anonymous when a paper is rejected.

Comment: @StrongBad "the publisher ignored it" I disagree. [According to Fiona herself](https://twitter.com/FionaIngleby/status/593408381060325376), they took about 3 weeks to respond to the appeal. Being slow isn't the same as completely ignoring it. PLOS have very publicly acknowledged this both [on their blog](http://blogs.plos.org/everyone/2015/05/01/plos-one-update-peer-review-investigation/#.VUO6vdTtlT0.twitter) and on Twitter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> While I think that blind peer review provides useful protection for reviewers, are Academic Editors generally provided anonymity?

In my experience this is rare but not unheard of.  For example, the [PNAS submission guidelines](http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/guidelines.xhtml) specify that the editor handling the paper will remain anonymous until the paper is accepted.  Presumably this is meant to protect editors from retribution over a rejected paper.  I'm not convinced this is necessary, but the existence of these policies indicates that someone must care.

> Further, is there any precedence for when a journal should reveal the name of a reviewer?

I'm not aware of any policy that allows journals to reveal the name of a reviewer without the reviewer's consent.  It could be reasonable in a case like this, but I wouldn't want to be in charge of writing a policy delineating when it is or isn't allowed.

Comment: In addition to the difficulties in writing such a policy, I am not sure I would review for a journal that had such a policy.

Comment: @StrongBad Knowing this would be a deterrent, but I actually have no idea what the policies are for any journal I've reviewed for.

Answer (score 8):

Anonymity, when used for any scientific role, is intended to make it easier for people to conduct honest scientific assessments.  It is not intended to be a shield from which to attack with impunity.

In business, there is a concept of "[piercing the corporate veil](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/personal-liability-piercing-corporate-veil-33006.html)," in which the shielding of corporate liability limits is removed in cases of gross misconduct.  Likewise, I think that it is reasonable to pierce the veil of scientific anonymity in cases of gross misconduct.  This recent case of "please add a male author" is one such; others could include abusive personal attacks or plagiarism.

I'm not sure that exact boundaries of such a policy would need to be spelled out in advance: simply saying "anonymity may be breached in cases of gross misconduct" may be sufficient.

Comment: What I find tricky is that I'd like to be able to assure referees that being wrong can't constitute misconduct.  (You are entitled to your own scientific judgment, even if it looks foolish or negligent to the authors/editors.  It might make you a bad referee whose opinion shouldn't be trusted or sought again, but it wouldn't mean you were guilty of gross misconduct.)  I see "please add a male author" as gratuitously abusive, not a scientific judgment at all, but I'm sure the referee would complain loudly that their honest scientific opinion was being oppressed thanks to political correctness.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician I think that certain types of misbehavior mean that people need to be called out and shamed.  I'd be fine to have that referee complaining loudly: bigots generally do.  It's not for the benefit of the bigot that we name and shame, but for the rest of society.

Comment: I agree that there's no need to feel sympathy for this particular referee, and I'd be happy to see them shamed, but I'm worried about making it clear where such a policy would be applied.  I've never seen a genuinely offensive/abusive referee report, but I've seen some lazy or foolish ones and some harsh ones, and I've seen authors who were offended by what seem to me to be legitimate differences of opinion.  I hope I'll never have to deal with a referee who deserves public shaming, but I expect that a shaming policy would cause some authors to ask whether it could be applied in their case.

Comment: For example, suppose an author submits a short, readable paper but the refereeing takes an extraordinarily long time.  Meanwhile, the author's tenure case is submitted or their eligibility for a prize for young researchers expires.  Has the referee committed gross misconduct by being so slow?  I'd say no, but some people might disagree.  Or what if a referee says something clearly negligent, such as "this method is well known, as the authors could easily have discovered by consulting an expert or even using Google" when in fact no other expert knows it and there are no references online?

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician In the first case, I would say we're definitely dealing with something within the normal standards of the community.  In the second case, we're starting to push into active negligence or hostility if the reviewer is making blatantly untrue statements---I think a reviewer should be expected to show their work.  I may have a fairly extreme view here, but I do think that such behavior is a form of professional malpractice and needs to be dealt with by a community, though likely not with "name and shame" as a first recourse.

Comment: Yeah, I think both (hypothetical) referees I mentioned are bad referees.  Currently, the punishment for doing a bad job is having the editors think less of you, which may or may not be a deterrent.  If the editors recognize a bad report, they will ignore or replace it (I can't believe that didn't happen at PLOS ONE).  Adding a further possibility of public shaming is not necessarily a bad idea, but it would lead to a lot of debate on how to apply it, and I'm not convinced it would end up being applied as sparingly as I think it should.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician For the negligent example you give, a couple of other considerations are: It may not be clear to the editor that this is blatantly untrue without a back-and-forth with the author & reviewer (and so far I personally not bothered to tell the editor when a referee has based a negative opinion on a blatantly wrong statement, though this has only happened once or twice to me), whereas a diatribe or sexist remark should be.  Also, it could turn out that this was due to an honest misunderstanding on the part of the referee, for which public shaming is inappropriate.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician But I think if one were to try to make an clarify a policy of "public shaming," it would be better to spell out a conservative list of things one could public shamed for (e.g., sexist reviews or a history of vitriolic reviews against certain researchers), possibly require warnings for a first offence, and have an appeals process for someone slated to be shamed.